# Store values for multiple rows in table

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

I have a stored procedure that runs daily to pull inventory numbers for our business. I've been asked to update the stored procedure to pull information on certain rows where a Purchase Order has been written on a part. For instance

Tbl A (Local Server)

```
partnumber    poNumber  ReceivedDate   PartStatus
```

Tbl B (Linked Server)

```
poNumber      partnumber  ReceivedDate
```

I need to look at only items with `TblA.PartStatus = "Shipped" AND tblA.poNumber = tblB.poNumber` THEN see if `TblB.ReceivedDate` is not null.

If the `TblB.ReceivedDate` is not null I need to set `TblA.ReceivedDate = TblB.ReceivedDate`

How do I set it up to loop through the table OR do a single join statement to make this quicker?

Comment: What is the key field in the two tables?  Is poNumber the key field?

Comment: Hello Vincent, Sadly none of the fields needed are key fields in either table!

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is:

```
UPDATE a SET a.ReceivedDate = b.ReceivedDate
FROM tblA AS a
    INNER JOIN tblB AS b 
        ON (a.poNumber = b.poNumber AND a.partNumber = b.partNumber AND a.partStatus = 'Shipped' AND b.ReceivedDate IS NOT NULL)
```

Comment: Hello Khalid, Thank you for your reply! This does work but I'd like to optimize this considering it takes around 15 mins for this pull to complete! Any suggestions with that? None of these fields are the keys in either table, I don't know if that has any value to this discussion.

Comment: I believe creating indexes on the columns being referenced in ON  clause should improve performance